# Angular Schema form - Override the input type of a field

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

Consider the schema

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Comment",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "gender":{
        "title":"Gender",
        "type":"string",
        "enum":["m","f"]
    },
    "comment": {
      "title": "Comment",
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 20,
      "validationMessage": "Don't be greedy!"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "email",
    "comment"
  ]
}
```

How can I override the html form type of *gender* from *select* to some another type(like input type *text*) without using the *x-schema-form* property and without rewriting the whole fields for the form (using the "*" and just altering the required fields). I tried the following form definition but the field repeats.

```
[
  "*",
  {
      "key":"gender",
      "type":"text"
  },
  {
    "type": "submit",
    "style": "btn-info",
    "title": "OK"
  }
]
```

The above definition will show two *gender* fields, one of type *select* and other of type *text*. My requirement is to display only one *gender* of type *text* where the *gender* of type *select* is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [v1.0.0-alpha.1](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/releases/tag/v1.0.0-alpha.1) the ability to use the key "..." has been added to allow adding the remaining undefined schema property keys in the form definition.